# can't change model instance

Tags: django, django-models

views.py

```
def patient_num(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = EditToBeSaveForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            num = form.cleaned_data['病人编号']
            new_p = Patient.objects.get(p_number=num)
            if new_p:
                new_p.p_name = form.cleaned_data['姓名']
                new_p.p_sex = form.cleaned_data['性别']
                new_p.p_age = form.cleaned_data['年龄']
                new_p.p_tel_number = form.cleaned_data['电话号码']
                new_p.save()
                return render(request, 'polls/patient_edit.html')
    else:
        form = EditToBeSaveForm()
        return render(request, 'polls/patient_num.html', {'form': form})
```

**models.py**

```
class Patient(models.Model):
    sex_choice = (
        ('男', '男'),
        ('女', '女'),
    )
    p_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, default='template')
    p_age = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    p_number = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    p_tel_number = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    p_sex = models.CharField(choices=sex_choice, max_length=2, default='男')
```

**forms.py**

```
class EditForm(forms.Form):
    病人编号 = forms.IntegerField()


class EditToBeSaveForm(forms.Form):
    sex_choice = (
        ('male', '男'),
        ('female', '女'),
    )
    病人编号 = forms.IntegerField(label='你要修改的病人编号')
    姓名 = forms.CharField(max_length=100)
    年龄 = forms.IntegerField()
    电话号码 = forms.IntegerField()
    性别 = forms.ChoiceField(choices=sex_choice)
```

after i populate the form and submit it, the view didn't update the database instance,why?

i can do it one by one in shell as below.

[image: update in shell]

**new confuse!when i populate the form with invalid value,for example, an inexistent id of Patient object,it will still render the template,why?**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Django Form request not saving data to db](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40282494/django-form-request-not-saving-data-to-db)

Comment: it's different,i have no indent problem

Comment: look very closely at your code

Comment: you do have indentation problems. I am not just talking about how your function body is at the same level as the function definition.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me your problem is that you never reach the code under the `if form.is_valid()` of your `patient_num` view. Try to add some prints after the `if form.is_valid()` clause and make sure your form is valid. It is expected that your model will not be updated if your form is not valid.

Comment: i had update my view but the problem still exist.could you tell what 'point' should i add for ?i  try to print the model instance but failed,there is nothing in shell.

Comment: that is the point. Python does not reach the code below the `if form.is_valid()` line. You should make sure that your form is valid in order to have you model instance saved.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem here that you are passing `request` to form instead `request.POST`

```
form = EditToBeSaveForm(request.POST)
```

Comment: thank you, it's a stupid mistake and i update my view ,however ,the problem still exist,could give me a hand?

Answer (score 0):

i put some 'print stuff' in my view and disvocer sth:

```
def patient_num(request):
    print(111)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        print(2222)
        form = EditToBeSaveForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            print(3333)
            num = form.cleaned_data['病人编号']
            new_p = Patient.objects.get(p_number=num)
            if new_p:
                print(4444)
                new_p.p_name = form.cleaned_data['姓名']
                new_p.p_sex = form.cleaned_data['性别']
                new_p.p_age = form.cleaned_data['年龄']
                new_p.p_tel_number = form.cleaned_data['电话号码']
                new_p.save()
                return render(request, 'polls/patient_edit.html')
    else:
        form = EditToBeSaveForm()
        return render(request, 'polls/patient_num.html', {'form': form})
```

i can only see 111 in the shell output.it seems that the view even didn't receive the post request.and i check my html file and find the problem.the form's  destination direct to another view function…… it's so stupid, i'm sorry for waste your time !